# Display WordPress Post Content in Multiple Columns

Tags: wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, advanced-custom-fields

I would like to display my Wordpress posts in two columns instead of one.

I'm using Bootstrap and Advanced Custom Fields. What I have works but the posts are repeated in both of the col-lg-5 divs.

```
    <div class="container">
    <?php // Display blog posts on any page @ https://m0n.co/l
    $temp = $wp_query; $wp_quersy= null;
    $wp_query = new WP_Query(); $wp_query->query('posts_per_page=-1' . '&paged='.$paged);
    while ($wp_query->have_posts()) : $wp_query->the_post(); ?>


        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-2">
                <?php the_category(', '); ?>
            </div>

            <div class="col-lg-5 left">
               <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
            <p><?php the_title(); ?></p>
            </div>

            <div class="col-lg-5">
                <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
            <p><?php the_title(); ?></p>
            </div>
        </div>


    <?php endwhile; ?>

    <?php if ($paged > 1) { ?>

    <?php } else { ?>

    <?php } ?>

    <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
    </div>
```

Comment: Well of course they are, because you are outputting them into each of those columns ... The whole approach makes little sense, because if you want more than one post in a _row_, then generating a _row_ element inside the loop for every single post is obviously not going to achieve that.

Comment: Sorry I should have stated that I'm a novice at this @CBroe

Comment: First of all, what is the actual end result you want to achieve - do you want _one single row_ with a left and a right column (where each of those columns would then contain half of the post); or do you want to create a _new row_ for every two posts? How the end result looks will mostly depend on that, because likely not all your posts will render with the same height; so you will either have two columns with no extra space between the posts (but instead probably a longer free space at the end of the “shorter” column), [...]

Comment: [...] or have two posts each starting at the same vertical position, and then have space underneath the shorter of those two posts, before the next row with two posts starts.

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is use columns in CSS.

Remove the additional column in your PHP file.

Apply the following CSS

```
.container {
    -moz-column-count: 2;
    -webkit-column-count: 2;
    column-count: 2;
    -moz-column-gap: 20px;
    -webkit-column-gap: 20px;
    column-gap: 20px;
}

.col-lg-5 {
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    width: auto;
    -webkit-column-break-inside: avoid;
    -moz-column-break-inside: avoid;
    -moz-page-break-inside: avoid;
    page-break-inside: avoid;
    break-inside: avoid-column;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
  <?php // Display blog posts on any page @ https://m0n.co/l
  $temp = $wp_query; $wp_quersy= null;
  $wp_query = new WP_Query(); $wp_query->query('posts_per_page=-1' . '&paged='.$paged);
  while ($wp_query->have_posts()) : $wp_query->the_post(); ?>



        <div class="col-lg-2">
            <?php the_category(', '); ?>
        </div>

        <div class="col-lg-5">
            <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
        <p><?php the_title(); ?></p>
        </div>



  <?php endwhile; ?>
  </div>
<?php if ($paged > 1) { ?>

<?php } else { ?>

<?php } ?>

<?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
</div>
```